# When should I put programs in "Program Files" and when "Program Files (x86)"?

Tags: windows-vista, file-organization

I'm using Vista, and installers often choose one of the two "Program Files" folders (regular or (x86).)  When I have the choice (i.e., there is no installer) how should I choose?  Does it ever matter?

(This question could probably be better tagged, but I'm not sure what it should be.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like you are using a 64-bit version of Vista (as am I). It should do this automatically but here it is:

64-bit in program files, 32-bit in the x86.

The separation is needed at times and should be withheld:
http://www.winvistatips.com/2-program-folders-64bit-vista-t171602.html

Comment: No offense, I accepted Mike's because he have slightly more information (that it doesn't really matter).  Thanks.

Comment: @Farmboy - I woul disagree with that assessment based on the votes.

Comment: Diago - I've changed my acceptance on the basis of the link IPX Ares provided.

Answer (score 7):

I don't believe it really matters because some programs that are 32 bit, will install in the Program Files (even though that's what the x86 folder is for). I believe its just for organization. So best practice would be

- 64 bit= program files
- 32 bit= program
  files x86

Comment: Why the downvote?  I'm ignorant of this stuff, If Mike is in error, let me know!

Comment: not sure... maybe for repeat?

Comment: perhaps i should have commented on IPXAres's answer instead of making my own. No harm intended there

Comment: Looks like it does matter after some more digging (I did not know either). http://www.winvistatips.com/2-program-folders-64bit-vista-t171602.html

Comment: aww man, now he goes back and picks yours. killing me ;) no worries, but that down vote hurt whoever you are!

Comment: I upvoted you Mike, if it makes you feel better.  :)